# Add Class only on browser Scroll Up

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, scrollbar

Is there any way to add class to an element only when someone scrolls the browser page up?

Problem [Filide>>](http://jsfiddle.net/oycv4hba/5/)

**JS**

```
$(window).scroll(function() {    
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (scroll <= 100) {
        $(".nav").addClass("darkHeader");
    } else {
        $(".nav").removeClass("darkHeader");
    }
});
```

Problem is this js add class when scroll-down page. But I want to add class when Scroll Up browser and after that when scroll down class will remove. 
 See Example [demo>>](http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Plugin-To-Hide-Sticky-Navbar-When-Scrolling-Down-Scroll-Up-Menu)

Comment: Your fiddle has `if (scroll >= 100) {` where as in your question its `if (scroll <= 100) {` ??

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know whether the user has scrolled up or down you need to track of the last scroll position. Then check if the new scroll position is greater or less than that position. You can then set the classes accordingly

```
// Script
lastScroll = 0;
$(window).on('scroll',function() {    
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if(lastScroll - scroll > 0) {
        $(".nav").addClass("darkHeader");
    } else {
        $(".nav").removeClass("darkHeader");
    }
    lastScroll = scroll;
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6x3hpra4/2/)

Comment: Hi, great but how to prevent adding class .darkHeader without scroll? please see your fiddle that .darkHeader will added after onetime scroll.