# I want my nav bar go back to bg-dark when i scroll up again

Tags: javascript, scroll, navbar

Here is my JavaScript Code... it puts my `nav-bar` in a special color when I scroll down, but when I go back up, it stays that way. I can´t make it go back to the primary color.!!

```
var myNav = document.getElementById('mynav');
    window.onscroll = function () {
        "use strict";
        if (document.body.scrollTop >= 200) {
            myNav.classList.add("bg-dark");
            myNav.classList.remove("nav-colored");
        }
        else {
            myNav.classList.add("nav-colored");
            myNav.classList.remove("bg-dark");
        }
    };
```

Comment: Question has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30559819/add-class-only-on-browser-scroll-up)

Comment: I might be wrong, but shouldn't `>=` be `<=`?

Comment: No, it doesn´t work if I do that. Thanks

Comment: Seems to work find in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/heybignick/wm0cmsd6/1/)